# AS/400 data queue are accesibles to node-jt400? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-midrange

I have an AS/400 machine and other machine with Node.js and Javascript application. Could I access to Data Queue with node-jt400?

It looks like Node-jt400 only has documented [Keyed Data Queues](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jt400#keyed-data-queues).

If I want access Data Queues Javascript my only one option is work with JavaScript applications on AS/400 machine?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/tryggingamidstodin/node-jt400), it looks like only Keyed Data Queues are implemented in this package. But it is open source, and you could fork it and implement unkeyed data queues if you like. This should be relatively easy since node-jt400 is based on jt400 which does support all types of data queues. You could use the keyed data queue support in node-jt400 as a model for your standard data queue support. Then, once you have your implementation working, donate that back to the project. I'm sure the owner of the project would appreciate the effort.